# How do I get Cypress to detect my existing Chrome browser after upgrade?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cypress

After upgrading from Cypress 3.2.0 to 3.3.0, Cypress opens with only the Electron option for execution.

I've tried completely uninstalling Cypress (both versions), and re-installing from scratch with npm.

When trying to do this:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Clear-App-Data

I get this:

```
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/wait',
     'C:\\Users\\James\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production' ] }
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I expect that Cypress when upgrading, wouldn't lose the location of the existing Chrome installation and that I would be able to debug the issue by clearing the app data without error.

Comment: Can you get `DEBUG` logs for Cypress? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging.html#Print-DEBUG-logs Upload those to http://pastebin.com and share them here.

Comment: after running ```cypress cache clear``` it showed Chrome in the dropdown, then my VSCode froze and when I opened again it was gone.  Here's my debug after opening it after that: https://pastebin.com/u6kLMHZ0

Comment: This is strange, it's finding Google Chrome but not adding it to the list of browsers. This looks like a bug. Can you create an issue so this can be fixed? https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Comment: Done. Thanks for taking a look.https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4260